# porcentajes en angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Hola amigos tengo un pequeño impasse, resulta que necesito mostrar unos porcentajes en mi web y estos vienen con su decimal:

> 50.893921334923
>   49.106078665077

yo solo necesito mostrar el valor entero para eso los separo por el punto con split y lo muestro con `$scope` pero el problema va en que si sumo los dos valores entero me da 99 y no los 100% es obvio porque la suma de los decimales lo completa pero para la vista NO.

de partida al numero menor le sumaba uno pero cuando la base de datos crece ya no sirve:

```
var enero = localStorage.getItem("enero");   
var febrero =localStorage.getItem("febrero");

var eneroentero = parseInt(enero.split('.')[0]);
var febreroentero = parseInt(febrero.split('.')[0]);

var enerodecimal = parseInt(enero.split('.')[1]);
var febrerodecimal = parseInt(febrero.split('.')[1]);

if (enero>febrero) {
$scope.febrero = febreroentero + 1;
$scope.enero = eneroentero;
}
else {
$scope.enero = eneroentero + 1;
$scope.febrero = febreroentero;
}

if (enero==febrero) {
    $scope.enero = eneroentero;
    $scope.febrero = febreroentero;
}`
```

Entonces como podría  aplicar una solución ?

Gracias.

Comment: ¿Podrías proporcionar  el código que tienes actualmente?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> yo solo necesito mostrar el valor entero

Tan solo usa `parseInt`:

```js
var n = 50.893921334923;
var n2 = parseInt(n);
console.log(n2);
```

En caso necesites redondear el número, puedes hacerlo por medio de:

- `Math.round`: redondea al entero más cercano (clásico)

  ```js
  console.log(Math.round(50.893921334923));
  ```
- `Math.ceil`: redondea al entero más próximo

  ```js
  console.log(Math.ceil(50.893921334923));
  ```
- `Math.floor`: redondea al entero más próximo (hacia atrás)

  ```js
  console.log(Math.floor(50.893921334923));
  ```

Answer (score 0):

En lugar de `parseInt` yo usaría `parseFloat`:

```js
var n = 50.893921334923;
var nn = 49.106078665077;
var n2 = parseFloat(n).toFixed(2);
var nn2 = parseFloat(nn).toFixed(2);
var result = parseFloat(n2) + parseFloat(nn2);
alert(result);
```